# VHDL: How to assign "integer range 0 to 99" as a new type name like typedef is used in C++

Tags: types, vhdl, alias, typedef, subtype

This is what I am trying to do in VHDL:

```
type score is integer range 0 to 99;
type speed is integer range 0 to 99;
```

But I think I have fundamentally misunderstood how "type" works in VHDL as the tool is generating error. It says `near "integer": syntax error`. I thought type in VHDL is similar to typefed in C++ but it seems it is not. What is the correct way to declare "score" and "speeds" as types, both of which are internally merely integer range 0 to 99?

Comment: Drop *integer* from both declarations. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.2 Type declarations.  And the caveat 'Are you sure you want to do this?' (and not an integer subtype? removing the *integer* creates a new type that isn't compatible with integer. `subtype score is integer range 0 to 99;` creates something that is.

Comment: Yes, I used subtype and it worked! Now, I better understand the difference between type, subtype and alias.

Comment: So I now understand that there are two ways to do this but using type will create something that cannot treated as integer

Comment: ... something that can only be interchanged with `integer` using a type conversion. Separate types are safer against accidents and misutderstandings, subtypes are more convenient. Both protect against out-of-range values ... do C++ typedefs do that now?

Comment: 5. Types, 5.1 "A *subtype* is a type together with a constraint." And this is semantically what you were trying to do. A new type with just a range is an integer type (5.2.3), just not type INTEGER, it has all the same arithmetic operators and compatibility with *universal_integer*. It's just not the same type as INTEGER, requiring explicit type conversion - 9.3.6 "Any abstract numeric type is closely related to any other abstract numeric type."

Answer (score 0):

Type creates a new type which has no relation with existing types at all.
Alias is just a different name assigned to an object that already exists like signal or variable.
Subtype creates a type from an existing type like a section of the integer range or a standard logic vector with a certain number of bits.

Therefore, to do what is required for this question, one needs to use subtype rather than type or alias.

So the correct VHDL will look like this:

```
subtype score is integer range 0 to 99;
subtype speed is integer range 0 to 99;
```